# Get exception when use gwtmobile lib

Tags: gwt, mgwt

I build application in gwt to smarphone up to now I used in mgwt.
I found another lib called gwtmobile.
I downloaded the lib from here
https://github.com/dennisjzh/GwtMobile-UI/downloads

I started to used in gwtmobile lib but I get exception 
"The import com.gwtmobile cannot be resolved VerticalPanel cannot be resolved to a 
why?
thank you everyone

Comment: Please check the import for  `com.google.gwt.user.client.ui.VerticalPanel`

Comment: firstly thank you for reply I can use the com.google.gwt.user.client.ui.VerticalPanel but I want to use in gwtmobile lib because this Appropriate to mobile

Comment: I have another question if I use just in gwt libs in mobile and not used libs like mgwt or gwt mobile i can build application to smartphone and the application work fine?

Comment: Yes there is no issue. GWT works perfectly. `classic` always works.

Comment: you right is worked but I have problem with ScrollPanel I add movie of scroll on android   device
http://s250.photobucket.com/user/gallavie/media/VID-20140504-WA0000_zps60ccd2f4.mp4.html        
and another problem is the color of widgets, all colors not show good the gray look like very bad

Comment: You can customize the color in GWT very easily using CSS.

Comment: 1) in movie the problem when I scroll the scrollPanel the border of textArea scroll with scrollPanel what I can do                      2) yes I change color in css to #eee but the color look like very bad is not look like in computer you understand me?

Comment: Sorry I have no idea about mobile application. Change the tag of this post to make it visible for others.

Comment: gwt does not have great LAF as all the widgets looks gray and also some of the widgets like gwt Calendar will not work in mobile.the gwt widgets problems like gwt-scroll are overcame by the mgwt scrollpanel and so on, also it has good community support .https://groups.google.com/d/forum/mgwt.